# UINavigationController: using SWRevealViewController error:Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, xcode8

I'm trying to implement [SWRevealViewController](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController) :

[image]

I'm trying to go from initial view controller to the SWRevealViewController controller:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"controller" sender:self];
}
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <UINavigationController: 0x7fd3b1013600>.
```

Any of you knows why I'm getting this error?. If I remove the ownership to SWRevealViewController in the last view controller it works just fine.

What I'm doing wrong?, I'll really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in `viewDidLoad`, the view not yet presented on the screen and the animation ViewController to present it is not finished. I think if you perform segue in `viewDidAppear`, this warning will dismiss.